# Magento 1.9.1 - Custom options to include cut/uncut vegetables

Tags: magento

I am new to Magento and trying to add custom options for vegetables.

Custom options include both cut and uncut vegetables. But both these should point to the same SKU and the quantity should get updated accordingly.

For example, 2.4 lbs of raw vegetable is required to produce 2 lbs of cut vegetable. Additionally, customer should be able to buy uncut (raw) vegetables too.

How to handle this? Where in every time when a customer orders for 2 lbs of cut vegetable, it should automatically deduct 2.4 lbs from the actual vegetable SKU?

Please suggest

Answer (score 0):

Admin -> Catalog -> Manage Attributes -> Create your attribute (cut/uncut) -> Manage Attributes -> move your attribute into vegetable attribute set

Comment: How do we handle to above said problem with just attributes alone?

Comment: mmm it may be more complex then what your used to.. persoanlly, i would make it so the attribute has some set quantity of lbs.. then every order would subtract from that but this requires coding thats quite lengthy

Answer (score 0):

Create an attribute, add it to the attribute set. Make sure the attribute is allowed to create configurable products.
Then create configurable products with the attribute.
Please refer the [link](http://www.magentech.com/documentation/how-to-create-a-configurable-product/) to know more about how to create configurable products.

Comment: But with this, how can i handle the situation where in 2.4 lbs of raw vegetable has to be deducted from the inventory for 2 labs of cut vegetable order?